# Write speed on Cloud Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In beta, it stated that maximum writes per second per database (at beta) is 10k. However, I am not clear on the context.

Is that means that for example I have 1 million record in BigQuery. When I want to write each row's record from BigQuery into each document, it can write 10k documents in a second?

Or, assume we have 100k concurrent users connecting to the Firestore and everyone of them perform 1 update, so after 1 second, it will have 10k successful write in the Firestore, which will take 10 second for the Firestore to complete all the write from 100k concurrent users?